# Domain Driven Design - modeling user registration process .NET Core

Tags: c#, aggregate, domain-driven-design, entity, aggregateroot

I am learning DDD and try to model user registration process using domain driven design. Lets imagine a dinner hosting system where Host and Guest are two entities. The host will be the one that will create dinner in the system and the guest will join the dinner, pay bill to host, rate the dinner, etc. Both host and guests will be the user of Dinner Hosting System. I have created three entities as below:

- Host (id, First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Mobile, ...)
- Guest (id, First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Mobile, ...)
- User (id, user_type (Guest or Host), Joining_Date, Status, ...)

Here, I see that a user cannot exist on its own. It will always be either a host or a guest. So in this system, there should be two aggregate roots - Host and Guest. And the User entity will be part of each aggregate.

Also the user will be registered as below

Enter mobile number and submit

- An OTP will be sent to the user
- The OTP will be submitted and validated by the system
- On the next screen, the user will enter and submit his First Name, Last Name, Email and Gender

As the complete user information is gathered in steps, and since the user can kill the app during registration process therefore, until the successful completion of last step, the user/host/guest entities should not be valid for the system, how can I create/save users/host/guest entities using DDD?

Comment: Do there really need to be separate models for every type of user?  Or should the type/role simply be an attribute of a user?

Comment: There could be different attributes. Here, I have listed only the common ones

Comment: Seems plausible a user could be a host and a guest, though not at the same dinner. If so, then tying the type to the user would mean a user could only ever be a host or a guest and never both (at different dinners of course). This makes me think dinner is the important part. Neither a host or a guest are meaningful without a dinner. The dinner would then be the context that defines what a user is at that dinner only. The dinner would reference associated users and the dinner would define which users are hosts and guests.

Comment: Yes, the domain concept is dinner itself. Dinner will reference the user entity and based on the user_type, the user will be identified as a guest or a host. My question is how should I model the user registration process (in steps) in DDD way? I have also edited my question

Comment: Does a user have to register every time they join a dinner or is the user saved and they just have to login the next time? If so, what happens when a user signs up as a guest and then the next dinner they are the host, and meanwhile they're also a guest of another upcoming dinner? I think dinner is the aggregate root and possibly users is another, I don't see host and guest as aggregate roots. Dinner would have the responsibility of adding users as either a host or a guest.

Comment: [Software Engineering - domain driven design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design) may provide more responses to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The central business entity of a web application's user registration system is the user. In order to maintain data durability, the RegisterUser use case interacts with the UserRepository interface and verifies the input data.

A database driver for storing user data and the web framework for managing HTTP requests are examples of components that are included in the external framework, also known as the driver layer. So User is one aggregate root which host and guest are inherited and nested for this.

the other aggregate root entity is Dinner, which different kind of dinner menus will be inherited from.

for more information
[Click](https://medium.com/bimar-teknoloji/understanding-clean-architecture-and-domain-driven-design-ddd-24e89caabc40)